# htaccess for url redirection with virtualhosts

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have an Apache server running 3 virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/sub1"
    ServerName sub1.domain.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/sub2"
    ServerName sub2.domain.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/sub3"
    ServerName sub3.domain.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

I would like to set up URL redirection on `sub3` so that when `sub3.domain.com/go/7dj29` is requested, it redirects to `sub3.domain.com/go/redirect.php?id=7dj29`.

I've created an `.htaccess` in `/var/www/sub3`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\/go\/([a-zA-Z0-9]{5,})$ /go/redirect.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

However, I receive a 404 instead of a redirect; what am I doing wrong?

```
Not Found
The requested URL /go/7uja8 was not found on this server.
```

Comment: @msg tried; no go.

Comment: @msg still 404 for me; is the rewrite flag I'm using correct?

Comment: `[QSA]` not necessary, apache will apend incoming qs if rewritten url doesn't have one. `[L]` should be safe, depends on other rules. Maybe append `[R]` just to see the rewritten url is the intended one? And sometimes browser caches act up. Try opening devtools and disabling cache.

Comment: @msg `<Directory />    AllowOverride none    Require all denied</Directory>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following rule works.

```
RewriteRule ^go/([a-zA-Z0-9]{5,})$ /go/redirect.php?id=$1
```

For apache to load rules from `.htaccess` you need *at least* `AllowOverride FileInfo`, but you can set it directly in `VirtualHost` context without it.

Comment: To clarify, I can set the directives on the virtual host?

Comment: @Kermit Yep. And I personally rather prefer it

Comment: That did it. Cheers @msg